# Why the JSON path is invalid into a JSON request for WSO2 ESB 5.0

Tags: json, request, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 5.0 since recently and I followed the tutorials on the website of wso2 about the healthcare example.

I'm actually on the "exposing several service as a single service" tutorial and I have been followed it at the letter.

The problem is that when I use curl to send a request to the back-end, I have some error messages in the log and the console that I Don't understand.

See the Following error message in the log:

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve, MessageID: urn:uuid:caca8c20-03db-4632-9f34-0b53f40d5950, Direction: request, message = Routing to grand oak community hospital
    [2018-09-14 17:22:28,616] ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.actualFee>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
    [2018-09-14 17:22:35,025]  INFO - LogMediator To: /healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve, MessageID: urn:uuid:605abc38-6543-44f3-963e-0412b0e7ad12, Direction: request, message = Routing to grand oak community hospital
    [2018-09-14 17:22:35,629] ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.actualFee>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
```

In the console:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
> POST /healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 234
>
* upload completely sent off: 234 out of 234 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Set-Cookie: SERVERID=s0; path=/
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2018 15:22:35 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
Error in executing request: POST /healthcare/payments* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Normally, the back-end will send a JSON file with some information about fee, the doctor, and the patient.

I Don't understand the error messages; apparently the error will come to the JSON path of $.actualfee but I Don't see a problem in it.
 Maybe the error is visible but I'm beginner at wso2 and I Don't unserstand all in the esb.

Arthur

PS: my XML source code of the HealthCareAPI.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/healthcare" name="HealthcareAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/querydoctor/{category}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Welcome to HealthcareService&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="QueryDoctorEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
    <resource uri-template="/categories/{category}/reserve">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="Get Hospital" expression="json-eval($.hospital)" name="Hospital" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Get Card Number" expression="json-eval($.cardNo)" name="card_number" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/RequestMapping.dmc" description="DataMapper" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/RequestMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/RequestMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
            <switch source="get-property('Hospital')">
                <case regex="grand oak community hospital">
                    <log description="Grand Oak Log">
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Routing to ', get-property('Hospital'))" name="message"/>
                    </log>
                    <property description="Set Hospital Variable" name="uri.var.hospital" scope="default" type="STRING" value="grandoaks"/>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint key="GrandOakEP"/>
                    </call>
                </case>
                <case regex="clemency medical center">
                    <log description="Clemency Log">
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Routing to ', get-property('Hospital'))" name="message"/>
                    </log>
                    <property description="Set Hospital Variable" name="uri.var.hospital" scope="default" type="STRING" value="clemency"/>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint key="ClemencyEP"/>
                    </call>
                </case>
                <case regex="pine valley community hospital ">
                    <log description="Pine Valley Log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Routing to ', get-property('Hospital'))" name="message"/>
                    </log>
                    <property description="Set Hospital Variable" name="uri.var.hospital" scope="default" type="STRING" value="pinevalley"/>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint key="PineValleyEP"/>
                    </call>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="Fault Log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Invalid hospital - ', get-property('Hospital'))" name="message"/>
                    </log>
                    <respond description="Respond"/>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <property description="Get Appointment Number" expression="json-eval($.appointmentNumber)" name="uri.var.appointment_id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Get Doctor Details" expression="json-eval($.doctor)" name="doctor_details" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Get Patient Details" expression="json-eval($.patient)" name="patient_details" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="ChannelingFeeEP"/>
            </call>
            <property description="Get Actual Fee" expression="json-eval($.actualFee)" name="actual_fee" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"appointmentNumber":$1,&#xd;
"doctor":$2,&#xd;
"patient":$3,&#xd;
"fee":$4,&#xd;
"confirmed":"false",&#xd;
"card_number":"$5"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:uri.var.appointment_id"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:doctor_details"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:patient_details"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:actual_fee"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:card_number"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="SettlePaymentEP"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Is $.actualFee part of the request?Can you provide the request which you are passing

Comment: @amg_amit my request file request.json contains the Following code : '{
"name": "John Doe",
"dob": "1940-03-19",
"ssn": "234-23-525",
"address": "California",
"phone": "8770586755",
"email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
"doctor": "thomas collins",
"hospital": "grand oak community hospital",
"cardNo": "7844481124110331"
}' and the back-end must return the Following file : '{"patient":"John Doe",
 "actualFee":7000.0,
 "discount":20,
 "discounted":5600.0,
 "paymentID":"e2781025-5332-4a78-950b-3be83c99fa76",
 "status":"Settled"}'

Comment: It seems the response from the ChannelingFeeEP does not containt $.actualFee, so it would help to see what message that endpoint is returning. If you put a log statement after the call mediator but before the property mediator you should be able to see the message that is returned by that EP.  You could also turn on wirelogging to see the messages. When you have the message you can check if the json-eval is correct.

Comment: @ophychius the response which is sent does contain actualFee, The message is getting converted into XML by default so jsonpath is not working on the XML element

Comment: @amg_amit I have just tested this and jsonpath works just fine. It even works if the backend response is xml. So there must be some other problem, for example the field not existing or having a different name.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Property mediator after call mediator like below.

```
  <call>
         <endpoint key="ChannelingFeeEP"/>
        </call>

 <property description="messageType" value="application/json"  scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <property description="contentType" value="application/json"  scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <property description="Get Actual Fee" expression="json-eval($.actualFee)" name="actual_fee" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```